# How to change backgrounds for specific rows using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to create a listview generated from information out of my SQLite DB.  I currently have the code set up to just display each row accordingly and populate 3 textviews with data.  I would like to be able to use some sort of If statement to check to see if one of values is "Room1" and then set the background of that row to a certain color.

This way each row in the list will have a different background based on what "room" the data is for.

I have tried extending SimpleCursorAdapter but I am a bit lost on how to get what I want out of it.

Here is what I have currently for the SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
Cursor notesCursor = myDbHelper.fetchDayPanelNotes(type, day);
startManagingCursor(notesCursor);
String[] from = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME, DataBaseHelper.KEY_ROOM, DataBaseHelper.KEY_TIME};

int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3};

SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main_row, notesCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(notes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend extending `BaseAdapter`, populating your list data manually and keeping a local copy of that data in your adapter class. Then when you implement the `getView(...)` method you can use the position or ID of the `View` you're generating to fetch the corresponding data to check against "Room1," and alter the `View` you return based on that comparison.

The answer by rekaszeru has exactly the right idea, but it sounds like you'll need more information than the position and ID, which is why I recommend going a level lower and implementing `BaseAdapter` directly.

Comment: For setting alternating row colors to a `ListView` knowing the position of the item in the data provider is enough (besides the color you want to set...)

Comment: That's true. That's not the goal of the question though. "each row in the list will have a different background based on what "room" the data is for"

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how this would work?

Comment: I wrote an example of extending `BaseAdapter` on AndroidCookbook: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=588

Answer (score 9):

You should override the `getView` method of your adapter:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.main_row, notesCursor, from, to)
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 0)
            row.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
        else
            row.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.background_light);
        return row;
    }
};
```

and set the background of the row based on the position (is it odd or even).

Comment: Using this method just to test the possibility shows some weird occurrences.  The list populates correctly, with each row alternating colors, but as soon as i start scrolling, all the rows become the darker_grey color, even if I scroll back up.  As soon as I reload the page it shows them alternating correctly until I scroll.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yes. You need to set the background color anyway, so you need the else clause too. These row views are recycled, doesn't get created every time they are laid out, so if one was used previously as an even item renderer, and now it's odd, you have to set it's proper background.

Comment: Of course instead of checking whether the row is odd/even position, you need to check if it's 'Room1' or not.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. 
Thanks to this post, I had exact same problem but after going through this, problem solved as shown below,

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, mNotesCursor, from, to)
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String s = cursor.getString(mursor.getColumnIndex("roomnumber"));
            final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("room1"))
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#480000"));
            else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("room2"))
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000040"));
            else 
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#004000"));
            return row;
        }
    };       


    setListAdapter(notes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I implement SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder on my Activity then override setViewValue...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {

    SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Initialize myAdapter
        myAdapter.setViewBinder(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {
        // Put code to process row data here
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work as well, because ususally you don't want to change the background of single cells, but the entire row. Cells can differ in height, making this solution look quite messy. Overriding getView() is better.

Comment: Look where I start my answer with "I implement..." and it's exactly what I mean. The app I was developing when I answered the question has a 'square' `TextView` at the left which displays time in a `HH:mm` format but the `Cursor` provides time in ISO8601 format. That square `TextView` also has to have a default black background or sometimes orange, sometimes red. To the right are between 1 or 2 other `TextViews` stacked vertically (depending on user preference). Those `TextViews` also have dynamic changes made. `setViewValue` works the best in my case. It was only a suggestion after all.