# Listview with different background

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android and working with `listviews`.  I am using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to populate the list.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.mytaskslayout, cursor, new String[] {"Aircraft","Discrepancy", "ARR_FLT", "ARR_Gate", "DPT_FLT", "DPT_Gate"}, new int[] {R.id.ac, R.id.discrepancy, R.id.arrac, R.id.arrgate, R.id.dptac, R.id.dptgate});

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

There are two types in the info that I am displaying, new task and old tasks. I would like to have different background color for those types. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: show your getView() or bindView() method to give you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend `SimpleCursorAdapter`and override the `newView()` method to accomplish what you want.

See other questions on this topic:

[How to change backgrounds for specific rows using SimpleCursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861335/how-to-change-backgrounds-for-specific-rows-using-simplecursoradapter)

Comment: Thanks. That's helping me. I tried the code from "rekaszeru" (lighter and darker gray background) and for me it's not recognizing "ViewGroup" (showing that red underline). In this case, where it's referencing to ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a SimpleCursorAdapter, as the name suggests, it's meant to be used in simple scenarios :). You will have to roll down your custom adapter.

Comment: thanks for replying. Is there an example of custom adapter, I can refer to.